# How to install a software using Jenkins job?

Tags: java, jenkins

I need to install software (.exe) on daily basis. So, I want to configure a Jenkins job to install given software.

Actually, when I install this software manually (by double click on exe), the installer will get launched and wants some selection points. For ex. Select some radio buttons, check boxes, and provide some values to text fields.

Could you please help me to know “**is it possible by Jenkins job?**” If yes, **can you help me to configure a Jenkins job to install software**?

Comment: It strongly depents on the installer software. Can you tell which installer product ist used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the installer software - if you can configure it for unattended installation then it's simple to set up a Jenkins job - how you'd call the executable depends on the installer. The site http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php shows how to do that for different installer software.

Comment: Thank you decocijo,
Actually, I want to install it silently, and yes, silent installation is supported by installer.
But my concern is how can I provide number of parameters to this silent installation?

One thing I found is use Maven and configure a text/property file to read the values, though due to some support restrictions i am not able to complete this.